# Tensorflow : Manually selecting the batch when training deep neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow

```py
# x_train.shape[0] = 54000

model.fit(
    x_train, y_train,
    batch_size = 128,
    epochs = 12,
    validation_data = (x_val, y_val)
)
```

When I am using this fit() method to train a neural network:

- batch_size = 128 means that I randomly pick 54000 // 128 batches of size 128 in my training dataset every epoch.

**Are those batches chosen with replacement?** I suspect from the docs they're not but I'd like confirmation.

**Can I manually choose my batches?** I would like to focus on specific images and not others for a given batch, by choosing them personally instead of letting randomness choose for me.

Comment: You will have to define a custom training loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are those batches chosen with replacement?

In each individual epoch, no. Of course the entire dataset is used again in the next epoch.

> Can I manually choose my batches? I would like to focus on specific images and not others for a given batch, by choosing them personally instead of letting randomness choose for me.

You should create a custom dataset for this, and leave the rest of the training loop (data loader, model etc.) unchanged.

But be aware that the samples in a minibatch are *supposed to be random*.

Comment: What you are suggesting is creating datasets by only keeping the images I want at a specific epoch (possibly duplicating them)? I know it sounds really dumb not to choose them with randomness, but it is precisely my goal.

Comment: Shuffling has nothing to do with your data set but is enabled in the data loader.

Comment: Yes, I know shuffling only happens when you choose "shuffle = True" in fit(). So if I don't choose this option, the batches in all epochs will always be chosen in the same order, correct?

Comment: If your data set doesn't do any shenanigans when mapping the `__getitem__` index to the actual data, yes.